# How do I extend the margin at the bottom of a figure in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, margin

The following screenshot shows my x-axis.

[image]

I added some labels and rotated them by 90 degrees in order to better read them. However, pyplot truncates the bottom such that I'm not able to completely read the labels. 
How do I extend the bottom margin in order to see the complete labels?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Two retroactive ways:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ...
fig.tight_layout()
```

Or

```py
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2) # or whatever
```

Here's a `subplots_adjust` example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_adjust.html

(but I prefer `tight_layout`)

Comment: You can also tell pass `tight_layout=True` to `subplots` which sa the same effect.

Comment: Is there a way to do this *without* using ``tight_layout`` nor ``subplots``? I.e. if one just creates a figure and adds a plot via ``plt.plot(...)``. The reason I am asking is because I am trying to create multiple plots for a movie and the title and axis labels wobble around if  ``subplots`` and/or ``tight_layout`` are used. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Wolpertinger: `fig = plt.figure(); fig.add_axes(...);` https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes

Comment: `subplots_adjust` partially worked for me, to add some space at the top of a figure where the legend was otherwise cut: `top=0.75` had an insufficient effect, `top=1.5`, strangely, seemed to have no effect. `tigh_layout` did not seem to have any effect in this particular case.

Answer (score 27):

A quick one-line solution that has worked for me is to use pyplot's auto [tight_layout method](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout) directly, available in Matplotlib v1.1 onwards:

```py
plt.tight_layout()
```

This can be invoked immediately *before* you show the plot (`plt.show()`), but *after* your manipulations on the axes (e.g. ticklabel rotations, etc).

This convenience method avoids manipulating individual figures of subplots.

Where plt is the standard pyplot from:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Good answer. It's worth noting that the comment "but after your manipulations" is crucial. Otherwise, your title may get cut off like it did with me.

Answer (score 15):

```
fig.savefig('name.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

works best for me, since it doesn't reduce the plot size compared to

```py
fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 10):

Subplot-adjust did not work for me, since the whole figure would just resize with the labels still out of bounds.

A workaround I found was to keep the y-axis always a certain margin over the highest or minimum y-values:

```
x1,x2,y1,y2 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((x1,x2,y1 - 100 ,y2 + 100))
```

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me.

Comment: The axis function specifies the viewport of the axes, so it's not clear why ``plt.axis()`` would help with labels that are outside of the axes...  It would seem more logical to expect something from ``plt.figure()``

Answer (score 1):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated, but it gives a general and neat solution.

```py
import numpy as np
value1 = 3

xvalues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
line1 = [2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 4.0]
stdev1 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3]

line2 = [1.7, 3.1, 2.5, 4.8, 4.2]
stdev2 = [0.12, 0.18, 0.12, 0.3, 0.35]

max_times = [max(line1+stdev1),max(line2+stdev2)]
min_times = [min(line1+stdev1),min(line2+stdev2)]

font_size = 25

max_total = max(max_times)
min_total = min(min_times)

max_minus_min = max_total - min_total

step_size = max_minus_min/10
head_space = (step_size*3) 


plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.errorbar(xvalues, line1, yerr=stdev1, fmt='', color='b')

plt.errorbar(xvalues, line2, yerr=stdev2, fmt='', color='r')
plt.xlabel("xvalues", fontsize=font_size)
plt.ylabel("lines 1 and 2 Test "+str(value1), fontsize=font_size)
plt.title("Let's leave space for the legend Experiment"+ str(value1), fontsize=font_size)
plt.legend(("Line1", "Line2"), loc="upper left", fontsize=font_size)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=font_size)
plt.yticks(np.arange(min_total, max_total+head_space, step=step_size) )
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
```

Result:
[image: Plot with headspace for the legend, big enough font, gridlines.]